# Error: Object with ID 'Asset:org.supplychain.food.model.LiveAsset' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I was trying to run this GitHub project https://github.com/Daniel-Szego/FoodSupplyChainDemo/blob/master/README.md
everything went fine except this transaction "consume" is throwing above stated error
The model file is

I have created each participant and assest and the asset i m trying to consume is atstate=resturant 
In historian i have seen the Steak asset is there and its current state is the restaurant that i am  passing the consume transaction but still not luck.

```
namespace org.supplychain.food.model

/**
 * ASSETS
 */

enum AssetStatus {
  o LIVE 
  o PROCESSED
  o CONSUMED
}

abstract asset LiveAsset identified by assetId {
  o String assetId
  o AssetStatus assetStatus
  o Double aggregatedGHG
  --> SupplyChainState atState
}

abstract asset Vegetables extends LiveAsset {
  o Double amount
}

abstract asset Animals extends LiveAsset {
  o Integer amount
}

asset Cow extends Animals{
}

asset Steak extends Animals{
}


/**
 * PARTICIPANTS
 */

concept Address {
  o String country
  o String city optional
  o String street optional
  o Integer houseNr optional
}

abstract participant SupplyChainState identified by stateId {
  o String stateId
  o String stateName
  o Address stateAddress
  o Double GHG 
  --> SupplyChainState [] stateFrom optional
}

participant Production extends SupplyChainState {

}

participant Processing extends SupplyChainState {

}

participant Distribution extends SupplyChainState {

}

participant Retail extends SupplyChainState {

}

participant Restaurant extends SupplyChainState {

}

/**
 * TRANSACTION
 */

transaction InitTestData {
}

transaction ClearData {
}

transaction Process {
  --> LiveAsset liveAsset
  --> SupplyChainState fromState
  --> SupplyChainState toState
}

transaction Produce {
 --> Production atProduction
}

transaction Consume {
  --> LiveAsset liveAsset
  --> Restaurant atRestaurant
}

/**
 * EVENTS
 */

event AssetProduced {
  --> LiveAsset liveAsset
  o Double creationGHG
}

event AssetProcessed {
  --> LiveAsset liveAsset
  o Double transferGHG
}

event AssetConsumed {
  --> LiveAsset liveAsset
  o Double endGHG
}
```

The Script file is
I am guessing there is problem with consume function at the last 
but i dont know much about it.

```
/**
 * Transaction file for food supply chain
 */

const namespace = "org.supplychain.food.model";

/**
 *
 * @param {org.supplychain.food.model.InitTestData} param - model instance
 * @transaction
 */
async function InitTestDataFunction(param) {  

      const ghgBsaeLineInfo = await request.get( { uri:'https://iaspub.epa.gov/enviro/efservice/tri_facility/state_abbr/VA/rows/102:102/JSON', json: true});
    const baseline = parseInt(ghgBsaeLineInfo[0].PREF_QA_CODE) / 10;

    console.log('init test data');

    console.log('Creating a Production state');  
    const factory = getFactory(); 

    // adding Production state 
    const productionReg = await getParticipantRegistry(namespace + '.Production');   
    const production = await factory.newResource(namespace, 'Production', "1");
    production.stateName = "Production";
    production.GHG = baseline;
    const newAddress = await factory.newConcept(namespace, 'Address');
    newAddress.country = "Bejing";
    newAddress.city = "China";
    newAddress.street = "Xia Mo Street";
    newAddress.houseNr = 16;
    production.stateAddress = newAddress;

    await productionReg.add(production);       

    // adding Processing State
    console.log('Creating a Processing state');  

    const processingReg = await getParticipantRegistry(namespace + '.Processing');   
    const processing = await factory.newResource(namespace, 'Processing', "2");
    processing.stateName = "Processing";
    processing.GHG = baseline / 2;
    const newAddress2 = await factory.newConcept(namespace, 'Address');
    newAddress2.country = "Hong Kong";
    newAddress2.city = "China";
    newAddress2.street = "Mua Mo Street";
    newAddress2.houseNr = 22;
    processing.stateAddress = newAddress2;
    processing.stateFrom = new Array();
    processing.stateFrom.push(production);

    await processingReg.add(processing);       

    // adding Distribution State 
    console.log('Creating a Distribution State');  

    const distributionReg = await getParticipantRegistry(namespace + '.Distribution');   
    const distribution = await factory.newResource(namespace, 'Distribution', "3");
    distribution.stateName = "Distribution";
    distribution.GHG = baseline / 1.75;
    const newAddress5 = await factory.newConcept(namespace, 'Address');
    newAddress5.country = "China";
    newAddress5.city = "Hong Kong";
    newAddress5.street = "Seeside";
    newAddress5.houseNr = 4;
    distribution.stateAddress = newAddress5;
    distribution.stateFrom = new Array();
    distribution.stateFrom.push(processing);

    await distributionReg.add(distribution);       

    // adding Retail State
    console.log('Creating a Retail State');  

    const retailReg = await getParticipantRegistry(namespace + '.Retail'); 
    const retail = await factory.newResource(namespace, 'Retail', "4");
    retail.stateName = "Retail";
    retail.GHG = baseline * 1.5;
    const newAddress3 = await factory.newConcept(namespace, 'Address');
    newAddress3.country = "Sydney";
    newAddress3.city = "Australia";
    newAddress3.street = "Beecon Str";
    newAddress3.houseNr = 122;
    retail.stateAddress = newAddress3;
    retail.stateFrom = new Array();
    retail.stateFrom.push(distribution);  

    await retailReg.add(retail);       

    // adding Restaurant 
    console.log('Creating a Restaurant State');  

    const restaurantReg = await getParticipantRegistry(namespace + '.Restaurant'); 
    const restaurant = await factory.newResource(namespace, 'Restaurant', "5");
    restaurant.stateName = "Restaurant";
    restaurant.GHG = baseline * 1.25;
    const newAddress6 = await factory.newConcept(namespace, 'Address');
    newAddress6.country = "Italy";
    newAddress6.city = "Triest";
    newAddress6.street = "Via Rue";
    newAddress6.houseNr = 44;
    restaurant.stateAddress = newAddress6;
    restaurant.stateFrom = new Array();
    restaurant.stateFrom.push(retail);  

    await restaurantReg.add(restaurant);       
}

/**
 *
 * @param {org.supplychain.food.model.ClearData} param - model instance
 * @transaction
 */
async function ClearDataFunction(param) {  
    console.log('clearing test data');

    // deleting assets
    const CowReg = await getAssetRegistry(namespace + '.Cow'); 
    let Cows = await CowReg.getAll();
    await CowReg.removeAll(Cows);

    const steakReg = await getAssetRegistry(namespace + '.Steak'); 
    let steaks = await steakReg.getAll();
    await steakReg.removeAll(steaks);

    // deleting participants
    const productionReg = await getParticipantRegistry(namespace + '.Production');
    let production = await productionReg.getAll();
    await productionReg.removeAll(production);

    const processingReg = await getParticipantRegistry(namespace + '.Processing'); 
    let processing = await processingReg.getAll();
    await processingReg.removeAll(processing);

    const distributionReg = await getParticipantRegistry(namespace + '.Distribution'); 
    let istribution = await distributionReg.getAll();
    await distributionReg.removeAll(istribution);

    const retailReg  = await getParticipantRegistry(namespace + '.Retail'); 
    let retail = await retailReg.getAll();
    await retailReg.removeAll(retail);

    const restaurantReg  = await getParticipantRegistry(namespace + '.Restaurant'); 
    let restaurant = await restaurantReg.getAll();
    await restaurantReg.removeAll(restaurant);

    console.log('clearing all data finished');  
}

/**
 *
 * @param {org.supplychain.food.model.Process} param - model instance
 * @transaction
 */
async function ProcessFunction(param) {  
    let liveAsset = param.liveAsset;
    let fromState = param.fromState;
    let toState = param.toState;

    liveAsset.assetStatus = "PROCESSED";

    // checking if transfer is valid

    if(fromState.stateFrom) {
        let isValidTransfer = false;
        await toState.stateFrom.forEach(function (state) {
            if(state == fromState)
            {
                isValidTransfer = true;
            }
        });
        if(isValidTransfer == false) {
            throw new Error('Invalid transfer');
        }  
    }

    liveAsset.atState = toState;
    liveAsset.aggregatedGHG = liveAsset.aggregatedGHG + toState.GHG;          

    if (fromState.$type == "Processing") {
        // producing meat from cow       
        // delete cow
        let liveAssetReg = await getAssetRegistry(namespace + '.Cow');        
        liveAssetReg.remove(liveAsset);

        // create 2 Steaks
        await ProduceMeat(toState); 

    } else {

        liveAsset.assetStatus = "PROCESSED";    
        var liveAssetReg;
        if (liveAsset.$type == "Cow") {
             liveAssetReg = await getAssetRegistry(namespace + '.Cow');        
        }
        else if (liveAsset.$type == "Steak") {
             liveAssetReg = await getAssetRegistry(namespace + '.Steak');            
        }
        else {
             liveAssetReg = await getAssetRegistry(namespace + '.LiveAsset');         
        }

        await liveAssetReg.update(liveAsset);    

        // emitting Transfer event
        let factory = await getFactory();

        let transferEvent = factory.newEvent(namespace, 'AssetProcessed');
        transferEvent.liveAsset = liveAsset;
        transferEvent.transferGHG = liveAsset.aggregatedGHG;
        await emit(transferEvent);            
    }    

}


 async function ProduceMeat(processing) {  
    let factory = await getFactory();

    // creating cell phone
    const meatReg = await getAssetRegistry(namespace + '.Steak');   

    // getting next id
    let existingMeats = await meatReg.getAll();
    let numberOfMeats = 0;

    await existingMeats.forEach(function (meat) {
      numberOfMeats ++;
    });
    numberOfMeats ++;   

    const meat = await factory.newResource(namespace, 'Steak', numberOfMeats.toString());

    meat.assetStatus = "PROCESSED";
    meat.aggregatedGHG = processing.GHG;
    meat.atState = processing;
    meat.amount = 1;
    await meatReg.add(meat);       

    // emitting create event

    let createEvent = factory.newEvent(namespace, 'AssetProduced');
    createEvent.liveAsset = meat;
    createEvent.creationGHG = meat.aggregatedGHG;
    await emit(createEvent);    
}


/**
 *
 * @param {org.supplychain.food.model.Produce} param - model instance
 * @transaction
 */
async function ProduceFunctionCow(param) {  
    let production = param.atProduction;
    console.log("prod 1",production)
    let factory = await getFactory();

    // creating cell phone
    const cowReg = await getAssetRegistry(namespace + '.Cow');   

    // getting next id
    let existingCows = await cowReg.getAll();
    let numberOfCows = 0;

    await existingCows.forEach(function (cow) {
      numberOfCows ++;
    });
    numberOfCows ++;    

    const cow = await factory.newResource(namespace, 'Cow', numberOfCows.toString());
    cow.assetStatus = "LIVE";
    cow.aggregatedGHG = production.GHG;
    cow.atState = production;
    console.log("prod 2",cow.atState)
    cow.amount = 1;
    await cowReg.add(cow);       

    // emitting create event

    let createEvent = factory.newEvent(namespace, 'AssetProduced');
    createEvent.liveAsset = cow;
    createEvent.creationGHG = cow.aggregatedGHG;
    await emit(createEvent);    
}

/**
 *
 * @param {org.supplychain.food.model.Consume} param - model instance
 * @transaction
 */
async function ConsumeFunction(param) {  
    let assetToConsume = param.liveAsset;
    let restaurant = param.atRestaurant;
    let factory = await getFactory();

    assetToConsume.assetStatus = "CONSUMED";

    const restaurantReg = await getAssetRegistry(namespace + '.LiveAsset'); 
    await restaurantReg.update(restaurant);    

    // emitting Sold event

    let consumedEvent = factory.newEvent('org.supplychain.green.model', 'AssetConsumed');
    consumedEvent.liveAsset = assetToConsume;
    consumedEvent.endGHG = assetToConsume.aggregatedGHG;
    await emit(consumedEvent);      
}
```

The Expected behaviour is that consume transaction runs changes state of steak to consumed but its throwing this 500 error code with error given in question heading.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the `Consume` function changes the state of the steak. So I assume you mean to update the asset. Your last line of code in the function is updating the participant restaurant and not the asset.

```
/**
 *
 * @param {org.supplychain.food.model.Consume} param - model instance
 * @transaction
 */
async function ConsumeFunction(param) {  
    let assetToConsume = param.liveAsset;
    let restaurant = param.atRestaurant;
    let factory = await getFactory();

    assetToConsume.assetStatus = "CONSUMED";

    const assetReg = await getAssetRegistry(namespace + '.LiveAsset'); 
    await assetReg .update(assetToConsume);    

    // emitting Sold event

    let consumedEvent = factory.newEvent('org.supplychain.green.model', 'AssetConsumed');
    consumedEvent.liveAsset = assetToConsume;
    consumedEvent.endGHG = assetToConsume.aggregatedGHG;
    await emit(consumedEvent);      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

= The namespace we have to get in below line is of steak not of LiveAsset and same goes for emitting event so in consume function in code **change**

```
const assetReg = await getAssetRegistry(namespace + '.steak'); 
    await assetReg .update(assetToConsume);    

    // emitting Sold event

    let consumedEvent = factory.newEvent(namespace + 'AssetConsumed');
```